# What is the difference between Rejection and Exception in akka-http

Tags: akka-http

I don't get the difference between Rejection and Exception in akka-http, they look redundant to me since they are managed almost the same way.

Is is not possible to have a Rejection of type Exception so in our Directives we can catch Exception and trigger the appropriate Rejection instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between [Rejection](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/rejections.html) and [Exception](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/exception-handling.html) is semantic.

Rejection allows you to do validation of request parameters. If some of the parameters do not match(incorrect for this directive) than directive can reject the request and some other directives can try to match request and handle than.

Exception means that you have unexpected behavior in your directive. Usually, it is after matching when directive processes request.

As I understand from your question you can have one of the situations below:

- You have exception while matching directive it probably means that you can not do proper validation and the only way is call function and look for exception. If an exception is thrown it means that directive does not match and you create rejection.
- You create rejection as a part of exception handling. It is one of the ways of handling exception. Another one is just returning response with 501 status code and Internal Server Error.

Both of this situations make sense but they do not mean that rejection and exception are similar things.